# Multiple gcc and linking between them

Tags: centos, gcc

I'm running centOS 6.3 which comes with gcc 4.4.6 and I installed gcc 4.6.3 using [these instructions](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC).

But when I type `gcc -v` it still says gcc 4.4 is the version I'm using. The newer version is under /opt/gcc-4.6.3.

When I run a `make` command do I have to specify a path to use the newer gcc? If so how do I do this, or can I replace the older version fully with the newer one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to rici for answering, his method works but I just found one that better suits me.

first I save the old gcc under a different name in case things go awry:

```
mv /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc_old
mv /usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++_old
```

then I link my new build to gcc and copy some important stuff:

```
ln -s -f /opt/gcc-4.6.3/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc
ln -s -f /opt/gcc-4.6.3/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++

cp /opt/gcc-4.6.3/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.16 /usr/lib64/.
mv /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.bak
ln -s -f /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.16 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

My thanks to Jacky Wei from the hiphop facebook git-team for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `make` which program to use for C compiles by setting the environment variable `CC`, and similarly `CXX` for C++. (That's assuming that you use the default rules or at least copy them. If you write your Makefiles with an explicit executable name for gcc, this won't work.) Otherwise, put something like this into your `.profile`:

```
export CC=/opt/gcc-4.6.3/<path to cc>  CXX=/opt/gcc-4.6.3/<path to g++>
```

You might be able to get away with just adding /opt/gcc-4.6.3/bin (if that's where the executables are) to your PATH.